# If $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{l} I_n$ then $[0,1]\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{l} I_n$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If a finite collection on open intervals $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{l}$ is such that $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{l} I_n$ does it follow that $[0,1]\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{l} I_n$? Clearly for every $x \in ]0,1[$ one can find rationals $r,q$ such that $r<x<q$ and the distance between $x$ and this points is less than any given quantity. Then, $r\in I_{n_0}$ and $q\in I_{n_1}$ for some of this intervals, thus we can find neighborhoods of $r$ and $q$ that are contained in each interval, respectively. Then I'd like $x$ to belong to some of this intervals, but it is not guaranteed that $x$ belongs to such neighborhoods. This is kind of circular reasoning.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\subseteq (-1,1/\sqrt{2})\cup (1/\sqrt{2},2)$, but $[0,1]\not\subseteq  (-1,1/\sqrt{2})\cup (1/\sqrt{2},2)$.

Comment: If you required the $I_n$ to be *closed* intervals, it would be true. But as is, the best you can say is that all points of $[0.1]$ *except for $l-1$ or fewer irrational numbers* are contained in the union.